# Github actions echo "$ABC" >> repo/abc gives error

Tags: github, github-actions

When I do `echo "$ABC" >> repo/abc` in github actions, it gives me an error saying the directory is nonexistent.

What is the issue here and how can I fix it. I am looking at another repos workflow and it seems to work there.

Please note that file abc doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by doing a ls and seeing the directory.

Repo/ didn't exist. Simply removed the `repo/`